# inline function in c

Tags: c, function, inline

Can inline function be declared in .h and defined once in .c?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`inline` function definitions need to be visible wherever the function is invoked. You can define the function in a .c file if you only want to use it within that .c file, otherwise you need to define it in a .h file so that the definition can be `#include`d wherever it is needed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  It can get messy though here is a good read:
http://www.greenend.org.uk/rjk/2003/03/inline.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function `static inline` and include it on a header file:

#### square.h:

```
#ifndef SQUARE_H
#define SQUARE_H

static inline int square(int num) {
    return num * num;
}

#endif // SQUARE_H
```